# PHP or JS: adjust color channel levels when converting image to black and white

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

I am looking for help on how to adjust the color channel levels of a black and white (or grayscale) image. In photoshop this feature is called the Black and White filter.

The examples below demonstrate my process. The red shirt (which is a perfect mid-gray) is black in the final image.

**Original Image**
[image]

**Changed Hue to Green**
[image]

**Final Image Now Black and White** (with mid-gray/red shirt black)
[image]

Comment: I do not understand your statement: *"red shirt (which is a perfect mid-gray)"* ??

Comment: In black and white photography, red is taught as a middle gray and a good color to meter light off of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Imagemagick, you would use the [-level](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#level) operator to adjust the black & white end points, which in turn, can be applied to a specific color [channel](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#channel).

Example:

```
 convert source.png -level 45%,80% out.png
```

With PHP's [Imagick library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php), you would use the [Imagick::levelImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.levelimage.php) method.

```php
$img = new Imagick('source.png');
$quantum = $img->getQuantumRange()['quantumRangeLong'];
$img->levelImage(0.45 * $quantum, 1.0, 0.80 * $quantum, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);
```

**Update**

To generate the intermediate image (green shirt), you would use the "red -> green" hue modulation with [-modulate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#modulate). Examples in [Hue Modulation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate_hue) docs.

```
convert source.jpg -modulate 100,100,166.6 green.png
// or in PHP
Imagick::modulateImage ( float $brightness , float $saturation , float $hue )
```

[image: Red to Green modulate]

Now for swapping the color for black, simply use [-fuzz](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz) and [-opaque](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#opaque). But honestly, all the green hues remind me of [Chroma Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) which is defined as...

[image: chroma key]

Once you have a mask isolated, it pretty simple to swap colors, backgrounds, or more complex images.

```
convert green.png -fx '1 * b - 1 * g + 1' mask.png
```

[image: shirt mask]

The main benefit of the mask approach is that the color details (shadows, highlights, & lines) will be preserved in the final image. Pulling this all together in PHP:

```php
$img = new Imagick("source.jpg");
$org = clone $img; // Copy source for final composite
$img->modulateImage(100,100,166.6); // Convert hues from red to green
/*
 Apply fx operations. Remember: K0, K1, & K2 are constants
 that need to be adjusted to match the chroma-key that you
 want to knockout.
 */
$mask = $img->fxImage('1.35 * b - 0.95 * g + 1');
// Copy the mask as the new alpha channel
$org->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

[image: original image with alpha mask applied]

For populating the shirt with black 80% (or gray 20%). Compose the new image over a color-only image, and drop to grayscale.

```php
$fin = new Imagick();
$fin->setSize($org->width, $org->height);
$fin->readImage("xc:gray20");
$fin->compositeImage($org, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$fin->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$fin->writeImage('fin.jpg');
```

[image: Black 80% with highlights]

Here's example with populating the shirt with a pattern.

```php
$pattern = new Imagick();
$pattern->setSize($org->width, $org->height);
$pattern->readImage("pattern:VERTICALSAW");
$pattern->negateImage(false);
$pattern->compositeImage($org, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$pattern->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$pattern->writeImage('pattern.jpg');
```

[image: Pattern Example]

Again, this is ideal if you want to preserve details. If you want to do a full knockout (eg. all green to black 80%), just use [-fill](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fill), [-opaque](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#opaque) & [-fuzz](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz).

Example:

```
convert green.png  -fill gray20 -fuzz 30% -opaque hsl\(33%,100%,50%\) black80.png
convert black80.png -colorspace Gray bw_shirt.png
```

[image: final shirt]

Comment: I added images to the example in the question.

Comment: I uploaded the center (green) image in my example to the Imagick library [test page](http://www.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/scripts/MagickStudio.cgi) and the levelImage isn't adjusting the green.

Comment: The second image (green hue) is perfect, just what I was looking for! The mask on the third image is good to know (especially for a future project), but I'm really looking for a way to get the third image to look like in my example. Is it possible?

Comment: BTW - What would the PHP syntax be for `convert green.png -fx '1 * b - 1 * g + 1' mask.png`

Comment: Another thought... after the hue is changed to green, could the green be replaced with say 80% black?

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the PHP syntax to `If you want to do a full knockout (eg. all green to black 80%), just use -fill, -opaque & -fuzz.`

Comment: @Jeffrey. There's [Imagick::opaquePaintImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.opaquepaintimage.php) & [Imagick::paintOpaqueImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.paintopaqueimage.php). One is deprecated over the other. So check your systems versions.

Comment: Awesome, I'm learning a lot. Now how would you go about doing the opposite and darkening the skin tone without darkening the whole picture (grayscale).

Answer (score 1):

Is it this command you are looking for?

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW5M0.jpg \
 -colorspace gray                    \
  b+w.jpg
```

Result (original red shirt on the left, black+white image on the right):

[image]  [image]

Or is it that you want the different red shades from the original to become (almost) pure black? -- In this case add some `-gamma` adjustment, maybe:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW5M0.jpg \
 -colorspace gray                    \
 -level 0%,100%,0.5                  \
  b+w-2.jpg
```

or

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW5M0.jpg \
 -colorspace gray                    \
 -level 0%,80%,0.5                   \
  b+w-3.jpg
```

Here are the two resulting images:

[image]  [image]

Of course you can play a bit more with the exact parameters I used here...

### Update

The following commands change the color level for the red channel first, then converts this intermediate result to grayscale:

```
convert              \
   red---QW5M0.jpg   \
  -channel R         \
  -level 0%,40%      \
  -colorspace gray   \
  -level 0%,100%,0.5 \
   b+w-4.jpg
```

or

```
convert              \
   red---QW5M0.jpg   \
  -channel R         \
  -level 0%,80%      \
  -colorspace gray   \
  -level 0%,100%,0.5 \
   b+w-5.jpg
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: can the shirt get darker without darkening the skin tone and background color? (that's why I added a middle layer to change the hue to green)

Comment: @Jeffrey: so you want the shirt to be (almoste) pure black (no different shades of gray) but the other shades of gray should stay roughly as they are?

Comment: there's a filter in Photoshop called Black and White and it changes the color photo to black and white but still lets you change the individual color levels. that's exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: @Jeffrey: I do not have Photoshop available, and I'm not familiar with it, hence I do not fully understand your explanation about how it works, and therefor I cannot really re-implement it as an ImageMagick commandline...  **:-(**

Comment: Basically, I need to go from the first color image to the third black and white image and being able to alter a color channel along the way. Your second to last image is close. Is it possible to use this approach using my second image (green) to get my third image (black and white)?

Comment: Also, do you know the php syntax for your second to last formula? `convert              \
   red---QW5M0.jpg   \
  -channel R         \
  -level 0%,40%      \
  -colorspace gray   \
  -level 0%,100%,0.5 \
   b+w-4.jpg`